# Need the first date and last date of the last quarter on the basis of Today's date in SAS

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

I need to extract the data of the last quarter on the basis of today's date. I need to make it dynamic.

Using intnx I am able to extract the last day, not the first day.

```
data _null_;
a = intnx('quarter',today(),-1,'end');
format a date9.;
put a;
run;
```

Can anyone share the logic how to get the starting and ending date of the last quarter?

Answer (score 2):

You only need a small correction to the last argument of the intnx function

```
data _null_;
start = intnx('quarter',today(),-1,'b');
end   = intnx('quarter',today(),-1,'e');
put start= date9. end= date9.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

From reliable [`INTNX` documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en):

The fourth argument, *alignment*, is optional

> ***'alignment'***
>   controls the position of SAS dates within the interval. You must enclose alignment in quotation marks. Alignment can be one of these values:
>
> - **BEGINNING**
>     specifies that the returned date or datetime value is aligned to the beginning of the interval.
>     **Alias**   B
> - **MIDDLE**
>     specifies that the returned date or datetime value is aligned to the midpoint of the interval, which is the average of the beginning and ending alignment values.
>     **Alias**   M
> - **END**
>     specifies that the returned date or datetime value is aligned to the end of the interval.
>     **Alias**   E
> - **SAME**
>     specifies that the date that is returned has the same alignment as the input date.
>     **Aliases** S, SAMEDAY    See   [SAME Alignment](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n1vvtep7sym1n2n1a6x9n1lqtcwf) for more information.
>
> **Default** BEGINNING
>
> **See** [Aligning SAS Date Output within Its Intervals](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p17dnb27j5gwqcn15w5hcsarhl35) for more information.